# How to continuously test whether my React application is showing up on the page?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, selenium, puppeteer, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to make sure that a certain React application is always on my website and if that is not the case (because the URL is broken or because of an error in the React app for example) then I want to receive some kind of alarm/notification.

Given a URL to some website, how to continuously keep checking whether the page reached via that URL contains the content (React application) that I want it to contain? Is there some way to set up an automated test that runs every X minutes which checks whether the React application is on the page and which will notify me if it's not on the page?

For example, [this page](https://www.amazon.com/deals) contains multiple React applications. By inspecting the page we can see that there is a `<div class="deals-react-app">` which contains a React application. The final solution/approach should work for this example and then also for any React application on any page.

Answer (score 1):

Route53 has [health checkers](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover.html) that can check [HTTP and HTTPS health checks with string matching](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover-determining-health-of-endpoints.html#dns-failover-determining-health-of-endpoints-monitor-endpoint):

> Route 53 **searches the response body** for a string that you specify. The string must appear entirely in the first 5,120 bytes of the response body or the endpoint fails the health check.

If this is not suited, then you have to develop your own custom solution. For example a **lambda function** running on a schedule that queries your website and verifies if its working.